# Select-String command returns filename, line number and text but I only want the text

Tags: powershell

```
@powershell -command sls "succeeded" pol_inst.log
```

gives me

```
pol_inst.log:259: Security Gateway policy installation succeeded for:
```

I don't want

```
pol_inst.log:259:
```

And I can't seem to find an easy answer

Comment: what is the "@" thingie supposed to do?

Comment: @JaquelineVanek It's the echo off character for command prompt.  He's calling from a batch file or from `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select-String "succeeded" pol_inst.log | ForEach-Object Line
```

Or to call it from the command line:

```
@powershell -command Select-String "succeeded" pol_inst.log ^| ForEach-Object Line
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `Select-String` returns you a collection of `MatchInfo` objects. Those contain lots of things in addition to the result.

Simple solution is to use `.Line` property like so,

```
select-string -path c:\myFile -pattern "myPattern" | % { $_.line }
```

Answer (score 1):

Expand the `Line` property of the [`MatchInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo_members.aspx) objects that `Select-String` produces:

```
Select-String ... | Select-Object -Expand Line
```